# How to set the Firebase: Realtime Database Rules to only let Unique names Childs

Tags: json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i am working on a project where users, can create a account with a username. This username should be unique and I have to set the rules in the Firebase Realtime Database. I am very confused at setting these up. I found some posts about that, but it didn't worked, here are my current Rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
   "users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'",
  }
},
  "usernames" : {
    ".write" : "true",
      ".read" : "true",
        ".validate" : "!root.child(\"username\").exists()"
    
  }

  }
}
```

And here's the Datamodel:
[I made a screenshot, how it looks in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmYfY.png)

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `usernames` rule to this:

```
"usernames" : {
    "$username": {
        ".validate" : "!root.child('usernames').hasChild($username)"
    }
}
```

[image: Using 'fred' as new user]
[image: Using 'bob' as new user]

Comment: Simpler and doing the same: `!data.exists()`. In words: validate that the current `$username` does not exist yet.